# Apache Camel Send Nothing To ActiveMQ Queue

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb, apache-servicemix

I want to send xml files content to queue. Right now I'm using this configuration :

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route>
    <from uri="file:H:/test/file"/>
     <recipientList>
        <xpath resultType="String">/data/destination/text()</xpath>
    </recipientList>
</route>
```

And my xml file content :

```
<data>
   <destination>activemq:queue:queueA</destination>
   <content>7500</content>
</data>
```

This config successfully send a message to queueA, but it has no content(empty message), so what is wrong with this configuration? Or is there any better way to send file content to a queue? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the message body is empty then this FAQ may help explain why: http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html

You likely need to enable stream-caching: http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html